# IBM MobileFirst 8 Direct Update on iOS 9/10 resulting in FAILURE_UNZIPPING

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I’m trying to get the Direct Update functionality to work on IBM MobileFirst 8, using the “hello world” examples for Cordova, while running on an iPad. The issue I’m describing below manifest on both iOS 9 and 10, where the Direct Update ultimately results in a FAILURE_UNZIPPING status.

At first, I was trying the example hello world Cordova application that is described [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/cordova/).

I’ve downloaded the MobileFirst Developer Kit (Product version: 8.0.0.00-20171024-064640), started the server, installed the sample adapter, add the iOS platform, and run the application on the device. I can connect to my local MobileFirst server just fine, and get the “connection successful” message when I ping my local server.

When I updated the web assets on the server, I would get the standard “update available” popup and then click update. After a few seconds, I would get a popup that says “Update Failed - direct update failure.”

Next I tried the “custom” direct update (described under “Customizing the Direct Update UI” in [this tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/).)

I downloaded the sample code at the bottom of the Direct Update tutorial. I modified the sample code to use the Direct Update custom listener that is described in the tutorial. So, my index.js file looks like this:

```js
var Messages = {};

var wlInitOptions = {};

var directUpdateCustomListener = {
 onStart: function (totalSize) {
  alert('onStart: totalSize = ' + totalSize + 'Byte');
 },
 onProgress: function (status, totalSize, completeSize) {
  alert('onProgress: status = ' + status + ' completeSize = ' + completeSize + 'Byte');
 },
 onFinish: function (status) {
  alert('onFinish: status = ' + status);
  var pos = status.indexOf("FAILURE");
  if (pos > -1) {
   WL.SimpleDialog.show('Update Failed', 'Press try again button', [{
    text: "Try Again",
    handler: restartDirectUpdate // restart direct update
   }]);
  }
 }
};

// Called automatically after MFP framework initialization by WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions).
function wlCommonInit() {
 // Override the default Direct Update interface.
 wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function (directUpdateData, directUpdateContext) {
  // Create a dialog.
  navigator.notification.confirm(
   'Custom dialog body text',
   // Handle dialog buttons.
   function (buttonIndex) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
     directUpdateContext.start(directUpdateCustomListener);
    } else {
     wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
    }
   },
   'Custom dialog title text',
   ['Update']
  );
 };

 // Used to trigger a request to the MobileFirst Server, to check for updated web resources. 
 WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
  .then(
  function () {
   alert("*** Obtained token successfully.");
  },
  function () {
   alert("*** Failed obtaining token.");
  }
 );
}
```

After updating the web assets on the server, I got the popup that says “Custom dialog title text - Custom dialog body text”, and then clicked “Update”. I then received the onStart callback and the onProgress callbacks for DOWNLOADING_IN_PROGRESS and UNZIP_IN_PROGRESS.

I did receive the onFinish callback. However, it says FAILURE_UNZIPPING in the status message. I never get the “*** Obtained token successfully.” to appear.

This behavior manifests regardless of whether or not I have the “application authenticity” turned on in the server admin console.

**Edit (10-31-17)**

If I run the [sample code](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/CustomDirectUpdate/tree/release80) from the custom direct update tutorial, but do not implement the Direct Update custom listener, then I just get an "Update Failed" alert after I see the download progress reach 100%. In that case, this is the output that results in the Xcode console log:

`2017-10-31 11:30:52.031281 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] Using UIWebView
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.033610 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.115991ms
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.036892 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 3.051996ms
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.037138 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.096023ms
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.038051 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [CDVTimer][wlapp] 0.721991ms
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.058316 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 20.061016ms
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.058473 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 25.121987ms
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.367226 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] Resetting plugins due to page load.
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.431251 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/74DE4873-55AD-49BC-A331-7EA868497397/CustomDirectUpdate.app/www/index.html
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.593785 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] Running static_app_props.js...
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.686195 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] Calling WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
    2017-10-31 11:30:52.734623 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '10.306885' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
    2017-10-31 11:30:53.241407 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [DEBUG] [OCLogger] No matching client configuration profiles were found at the IBM MobileFirst Platform server. Logger now using local configurations.
    2017-10-31 11:30:54.250540 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '47.857178' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
    2017-10-31 11:30:54.326299 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
    2017-10-31 11:30:54.327089 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
    2017-10-31 11:31:08.869725 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] THREAD WARNING: ['WLDirectUpdatePlugin'] took '10.709961' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
    2017-10-31 11:31:09.963788 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057363] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process CustomDirectUpdate
    2017-10-31 11:31:09.964872 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057363] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
        filterBlacklist =     (
        );
        filterWhitelist =     (
        );
        restrictWeb = 1;
        useContentFilter = 0;
        useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
        whitelistEnabled = 0;
    }
    2017-10-31 11:31:09.966253 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057363] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
    2017-10-31 11:31:11.966408 CustomDirectUpdate[4624:2057281] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '29.916016' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.`

**End-Edit (10-31-17)**

What step am I missing to get the "SUCCESS" status message upon Direct Update completion? If anyone has any ideas, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you share the app you are running? I have tried with the same mfp-cordova version with the code shared by you above but did not find any errors. The custom update is happening successfully.

Comment: Hi @Keerthi -- thanks for asking so quickly! [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzwQM5nNyRE-LUdBWVY4bHZzNXM/view?usp=sharing) is the Cordova code, with the exception that I emptied some of the node_modules and plugins directories to save space. It is literally the same [sample code](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/CustomDirectUpdate/tree/release80) that the custom Direct Update tutorial refers to. The only exceptions are that I modified the index.js file to incorporate the directUpdateCustomListener per the tutorial, and I changed the app ID, to run on an iPad.

Comment: If you run the customDirectupdate sample as-is, do you see it working fine? Also, do you see any client side errors ? In XCode console?

Comment: Hi @VivinK -- thank so much for the reply. I've updated the post (Edit (10-31-17) to End-Edit (10-31-17)) with the Xcode client logs. Basically, I get the custom popup, then the download progress reaches 100%, and finally I get an "Update Failed - Direct Update failure" popup. There was nothing that I could tell from the Xcode client logs that looked like an error. When I don't trigger the Direct Update, then I do get the "*** Obtained token successfully" console log message. Thanks!